# Shiny App work on Rstudio but not on server

Tags: r, shiny-server

I am making a Shiny App. It works well with RStudio. It runs perfectly with all 3 modes, i.e. run in window, run in viewer panel and run external. The interface should look like below when first loaded.
[image: Interface when loaded in Rstudio]

However, when I publish to the Shiny server, it look crazy like below:
[image: Interface when loaded after publish to Shiny Server]

I tried to search online and on stackoverflow, but got no clue about it. So, what's wrong?

Comment: It appears that a CSS file is missing when you publish to Shiny server.

Comment: @RyanNerd: Thank you very much.

Comment: Still not exactly sure what's going on. I just downloaded the latest version Rstudio and shiny library and it worked. I am guessing it's the version conflict issue.

Comment: Good to hear you got this working.